# Why is Matlab function interpn being modified?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

The Matlab function interpn does n-grid interpolation. According to the documentation page:

> In a future release, interpn will not accept mixed combinations of row and column vectors for the sample and query grids.

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btwcr8z-1) page provides a bit more information but is still kind of cryptic.

My question is this: **Why is this modification being implemented? In particular, are there any pitfalls to using interpn?**

I am writing a program in fortran that is supposed to produce similar results to a Matlab program that uses interpn as a crucial component. I'm wondering if the Matlab program might have a problem that is related to this modification.

Comment: for the why you need to ask Mathworks. Personally I wonder why they ever accepted such combinations. As you don't even name your program the answer is *maybe*. But nobody forces you to update Matlab if you worry.

Comment: I agree you should email MathWorks about this. If I understand correctly, it looks like this will prevent you from using vectors of different orientations as [grid vectors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interpn.html#bt2rijt), but you can always us throw the grid vectors into [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html?searchHighlight=ndgrid) and pass the output of that to `interpn` to get the equivalent result. So at worst this will mean adding one extra line of code each time you call `interpn`. This seems like a strange change to make so I may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @eigenchris. @bdecaf, I don't quite understand your comment concerning worrying. I was attempting to ask a general question and wanted to motivate why I was interested in knowing it a bit (my actual program estimates a [Krusell-Smith](http://www.econ.yale.edu/smith/250034.pdf) model). Perhaps a better way to state my question would have been to ask if there were any known pathologies associated with `interpn`. I don't generally use Matlab so I thought I'd see if anyone who did knew anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think this indicates that there is any sort of problem with using `interpn`, or any of the other MATLAB interpolation functions.

Over the last few releases MathWorks has been introducing some new/better functionality for interpolation (for example the `griddedInterpolant`, `scatteredInterpolant` and `delaunayTriangulation` classes). This has been going on in small steps since R2009a, when they replaced the underlying [QHULL](http://www.qhull.org/) libraries for computational geometry with [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/).

It seems likely to me that `interpn` has for a long time supported an unusual form of input arguments (i.e. mixed row and column vectors to define the sample grid) that is probably a bit confusing for people, hardly ever used, and a bit of a pain for MathWorks to support. So as they move forward with the newer functionality, they're just taking the opportunity to simplify some of the syntaxes supported: it doesn't mean that there is any problem with `interpn`.